# Response.BinaryWrite not working with Safari in MAC

Tags: asp.net, macos, safari, response.write

I'm using the following code to send a PDF to the browser

```
        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.ClearHeaders();
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", fileBytes.Length.ToString());
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        Response.BinaryWrite(fileBytes);
        Response.Flush();
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
```

It works well (pdf is embedded properly within the browser) for all browsers except Safari (version 5.x) in MAC. Also, it is working properly for Firefox and Chrome in MAC.
I'm wondering is it a browser issue? or there is something wrong with Response.BinaryWrite?

**[Edit]**
Safari behavior, the pdf is not loaded at all. One progress bar is shown and keep loading, may be it's related to the PDF plugin which is installed? So, how to figure out the why this behavior in Safari?

**[Edit]**
This error is logged in Safari Developer Tools console "Failed to load resource: Plug-in handled load" which seems that it's related to the PDF plugin.

Comment: The PDF is not loaded at all? One progress bar is there? May be that progree bar is related to the Adobe plugin which is installed.

Comment: @Ahmed: What happens when the progress bar is complete? Does it open pdf in browser?

Comment: @Razvan, the problem that it keeps loading seems to be stuck

Comment: Using Safari Developer Tools, an error is logged "Failed to load resource: Plug-in handled load", so how to figure out why it's not loading?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it's working with me fine

```
        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.ClearHeaders();
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.AppendHeader("Accept-Header", attachmentObj.AttachmentFile.Length.ToString());
        Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(attachmentObj.Description, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8) + "\"");
        Response.AppendHeader("Pragma", "public");
        Response.BinaryWrite((byte[])attachmentObj.AttachmentFile.ToArray());        
        Response.Flush();
        Response.End();
```

Comment: The Failed to load resource: Plug-in handled load error still logged in Console log while loading of page.